# Can selenium on python get value of a <div class>?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

For example:

```
<div class="xpto">Some text</div>
```

How can I get the "Some text" ?

I have this:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
message_received = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[36]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div') # xpath of element
text_obtained = message_receiver. #dont know what to put here
```

Answer (score 0):

Show that part of webpage you want to get. And try `message_received.text`

Answer (score 0):

To get the innerText **Some text** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *text*:

  ```
  print(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[36]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div').text)
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[36]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div').get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```